# Jframe. Cant get multiple components to display

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, components

I am having trouble getting two different components to display at the same time.

```
public class BandViewer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(1000, 800);
      frame.setTitle("band");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      BandComponent component = new BandComponent();
      ConcertBackground component1 = new ConcertBackground();
      frame.add(component);
      frame.add(component1);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Now I read on this forum that you can do something to display both at the same time but wasn't able to figure out how it was done. Can anyone please help? I want to have one to be in front of the other. Is their some way to control the layering? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Within a `JFrame` a Layout Manager is usually used to position different components, tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Something like:

```
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

To set up a a basic layout manager for your `JFrame`. There is also a `JLayeredPane` which allows you to specify a z-order - [docs page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), so something like:

```
JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();

BandComponent component = new BandComponent();
ConcertBackground component1 = new ConcertBackground();
layeredPane.add(component, 0); // 0 to display underneath component1
layeredPane.add(component1, 1);

contentPane.add(layeredPane);
```

A display hierachy is set up in this manner, with objects within objects. I'm not sure what `BandComponent` and `ConcertBackground` classes are, but if they inherit from Swing classes you might have to set a preferred size or similar to ensure they don't have a zero size!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because `JFrame` by default uses a `BorderLayout`.  `BorderLayout` only allows a single component to appear in any one of it's five available positions.

To add multiple components to a single container, you need to configure the layout or use one which better meets your needs...

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more examples